# making select-boxes required if appropriate radio button selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wanted to make my 2 select boxes required if they select the radio button foreign language so they can make the choices of what language they want and at which level was not sure exactly how to accomplish this

```
<label for"artlang"=""> Fine Arts or Language: </label><br>
<input name="ArtLang" type="radio" value="Art150" required>Art 150<br>
<input name="ArtLang" type="radio" value="Mus150"required>Music 150 <br>
<input name="ArtLang" type="radio" value="Lang"required>Foreign Language 



<label for="language">Language: </label>
<select name="language">
<option name"="" "="" value=" "> </option>
<option name="chinese" value="chinese">Chinese</option>
<option name="french" value="french">French</option>
<option name="german" value="german">German</option>
<option name="greek" value="greek">Greek</option>
<option name="italian" value="italian">Italian</option>
<option name="japanese" value="japanese">Japanese</option>
<option name="latin" value="latin">Latin</option>
<option name="russian" value="russian">Russian</option>
<option name="spanish" value="spanish">Spanish</option>
</select>


<label for="languagelevel">Level: </label>
<select name="languagelevel"> 
<option name"="" "="" value=" "> </option>
<option name="Elementary" value="elementary">Elementary</option>
<option name="intermediate" value="intermediate">Intermediate</option>
<option name="advanced" value="advanced">Advanced</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Have you looked at the [JQuery Validation plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/)? That works well for this kind of thing, if you don't mind using a plugin.

Comment: Listen for `.on('change', ...)` for the radio button elements. When they change, check if "Foreign Language" is selected. If so, select the menus and set the `required` attribute. Otherwise, select the menus and `.removeAttr("required")`.